# popup WYSIWYG editor ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have to have a popup WYSIWYG editor into my ROR application. I want to develop the editor like www.wikispaces.com used. Here they used Jquery (if you want like that editor , you need to login ) . I want the same functionality . Can anyone please suggest how can i do this and please give me the reference site for the development JQuery with WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick google search turns up jwysiwyg: http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/

And there seem to be some articles on how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), it works very well.